# Remove Inverted duplicates - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to remove duplicates, but they don't appear as duplicates.
Is there a query to help removing this to onlyleave one behind?

[image]

Comment: So which is the correct one to leave? Neither look like driver names?

Comment: any one of the two can stay

Comment: Do you want to "remove" duplicates in a `SELECT` query, or do you want to make modifications to the table itself? Are you interested in *preventing* such duplicates from ever being introduced in the first place? And we need you to pick a rule for which one to keep - you may not care, but in general, in SQL, you have to articulate a rule - so it would be better if you actually make a decision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this will group the rows by the two fields in sorted order and delete all but one.
I'm presuming both fields must match and you have a primary key named TableId.

```
DELETE
    T
FROM
    [Table] T
JOIN (
    SELECT
        TableId,
        [Name],
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY [Name] ORDER BY TableId DESC ) RowId
    FROM (
        SELECT
            TableId,
            Reg_Num + '|' + Driver_Name AS [Name]
        FROM
            [Table]
        WHERE
            Reg_Num <= Driver_Name
        UNION
        SELECT
            TableId,
            Driver_Name + '|' + Reg_Num AS [Name]
        FROM
            [Table]
        WHERE
            Driver_Name < Reg_Num
        ) Y
    ) X ON
        X.TableId = T.TableID
WHERE
    RowId > 1
```

Answer (score 2):

This query will yield normalized values ( if they all varchars) which you can now check duplicates against

```
select 
    [someId], 
    case 
       when reg_num < driver_name then reg_num + driver_name 
                                  else driver_name + reg_num 
    end as combination
```